# Can I overrid the message in the NOTIFICATIONS AFTER JOB COMPLETION in job definition?

Tags: variables, control-m

I'd like to override the message that was coded for the 'Notifications after job completion' when submitting a job to control-m, by setting a variable at the time. I haven't found if that 'message' is a type of variable that can be defined.

Answer (score 0):

No, the message field is not a variable. However, you can use lots of variables to construct the message.

You can also create multiple messages that are triggered on (for example) output text or exit codes. You can even update variables based on output/RC (which can be used in the message).